# Map isn't loading on Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-maps-api-3

I have this code with Google Maps, but in the emulator I only see the yellow Pegman icon. Everything else is grey and the map isn't loading.

```
function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }
    function onDeviceReady() {

    }

var map;
function initialize() {

     var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14  
  };
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);


  // Try HTML5 geolocation
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: 'contentstring'
       });


        var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: pos,
           map: map,
           title: 'ciao!'

     }); 

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker1);
    });


    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: new google.maps.LatLng( 45.4353135, 12.135795400000006 ),
           map: map,
           title: 'ciao!'

     }); 



      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }
}

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
  if (errorFlag) {
    var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
  } else {
    var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
  }

  var options = {
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
    content: content
  };

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
  map.setCenter(options.position);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Also, how can I change the marker icon? I can't seem to get it to work currently.

Comment: what is your error console ..?

Comment: What version of Android are you using?

Comment: I do not by any mistake , and I'm using Android 5.1.1 and API 22 .
Simply I do not know how to enter and in which order the code " deviceready " of cordova .

Comment: Using the emulator ripple chroome , and the map only works if I turn the screen horizontally or loads the page manually with " #pagename "

Comment: The way you set up the listener should be correct. How did you include the cordova.js script?